# Getting 424 Runtime error, object required

Tags: vba

Please help with the code error 424 below

```
Public counter As String

Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    If ActiveSheet1.Name = Sheet2.Name Then
        If counter = 0 Or counter = Null Then
            Call LLP_Hide
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove 1 from `ActiveSheet1`.

If `counter` is meant to count it should be declared as `Integer` type instead of `String`.

Anyway, this part of code will also cause error: `counter = 0`. Replace it with `counter = "0"` or change the type of `counter`.

```
Public counter As Integer

Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    If ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet2.Name Then
        If counter = 0 Then
            Call LLP_Hide
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I have modified the code as mentioned, but still the same error:

Comment: Check if you have worksheet `Sheet2` in your VBA project.